# Why can`t I fetch from mysql using PHP on the second time?

Tags: php, mysql

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?php
  //error_reporting(E_ALL);
  //ini_set('display_errors', '1');

  // 1. Create a database connection
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "name";
  $dbpass = "password";
  $dbname = "widget_corp";
  $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
         mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
?>
<?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    // Test if there was a query error
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Databases</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";
                echo "<hr />";
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";
                echo "<hr />";
            }
        ?>

        <?php
          // 4. Release returned data
          mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
  // 5. Close database connection
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I want the returned data to be printed twice in different formats.

However, when I run the program, only `mysqli_fetch_row` is printed (`mysqli_fetch_assoc` is not printed).

Can you please clarify why?

Comment: A clear "why" is difficult to line out: it is not that this would not be possible to implement. But it simply is not the way the database driver `mysqli` is working internally. This is not about right or wrong, just about how things are. The driver increments the internal pointer in the result set. Therefore you cannot request the same entry in the result twice the way you do. You have to tell the driver you want to do that because it is not how it is normally used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first loop steps through to the end of the result set, so there is nothing more to fetch. You need to reset the pointer (the cursor's position in the result set) between loops using [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php).

Example:

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($row);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<hr />";
        }

        mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); // this resets the cursor to the first row

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($row);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<hr />";
        }
```

Also, please note that you do not need so many `<?php ... ?>` blocks -- you can combine adjacent blocks of code. Just delete any of these combos:

```
?>
<?php
```

Comment: Does this function knows to reset the pointer back to the beginning of the returned set, or should I add some argument to the function? Can I tell the pointer to which row in the fetched data to go to? or is this function just resets to the BEGINNING of the fetched data?

Comment: Read the linked doc page?

Comment: it is worth noting that adding a second variable to hold the results like: $result = $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query); and using that on your next loop: mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) would also fail because the variable points to the same mysqli_result object. Doing another query would work:  $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query) though, but why initiate another call when you could just do a pointer reset as this solution suggests.

Comment: @Qwerty It can jump to any point in the result set. The second argument (`0` in the code above) specifies the row to use.